# How to print multiple copies of an image on a single page

Tags: printing, pdf

I have an image, about 300x300 pixels large. I want to print as many copies as possible on a single page (I am planning to cut them apart with scissors afterwards).

Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to generate a PDF with copies (without opening something like gimp and manually doing copy-paste work).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s `montage` tool.

1. Install the imagemagic tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
   ```
2. Combine your images. I have created this image, called `foo.png` as a demonstration:

   [image]

   Run `montage`, telling it to make 3 rows of 5 images each (`-tile 3x5`), keeping the original size of the image (`-geometry 300x400`  and give it the same image 15 times as input:

   ```
   montage -geometry 300x400 -tile 3x5 foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png \
    foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png  montage.ps
   ```

   The result is:

   [image]
3. Since that creates a postscript file (the language printers speak), you can print it directly from the command line using tools like `lp` or `enscript`. I don't have a printer at the moment so I can't check but this should work

   ```
   lp montage.ps
   ```

   or

   ```
   enscript montage.ps
   ```

Comment: Hey,
Tried this but I think the DPI is wrong, the images come out pixelated. `-density 300x300` does not seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuySoft when you print them or in the image itself as well? Try using fewer images: `montage foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png -tile 2x3  montage.ps`, just play around with the settings, you probably just need to get the number right so it fits on a single page. Also try Rinzwind's approach.

Comment: Would have tried @Rinzwind but not next to a printer now. Trying to figure out how to print to file with Rinzwind's solution.
Also changing the tile number does not help, I should be able to fit much more on a page.
[http://imgur.com/rbEj6Ee](Here is my image for reference).

Comment: @GuySoft use the `-geometry` option to set the size of each image: `montage -geometry 303x453 foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png  foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png foo.png -tile 3x  montage.pdf` gives me [this pdf](http://imgur.com/0rTeFvQ).

Comment: '-geometry' works I can generate PDF like this. thanks!

Comment: Note that the dimensions given in '-geometry` refer to the pixel size of each tile, not of the whole output file.

Comment: pdf output option is better than ps.

Answer (score 9):

From [Command-Line Printing in Linux](http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/kb/printing/linux-command-line).

> N-Up Printing
>
> The -o number-up=value option selects N-Up printing. N-Up printing
>   places multiple document pages on a single printed page. CUPS supports
>   1, 2, 4, 6, 9, and 16-Up formats; the default format is 1-Up:
>
> ```
> lp -o number-up=1 filename 
> lp -o number-up=2 filename 
> lp -o number-up=4 filename 
> lpr -o number-up=16 filename
> ```
>
> The -o number-up-layout=value option chooses the layout of the pages
>   on each output page:
>
> ```
> -o number-up-layout=btlr
> Bottom to top, left to right
> -o number-up-layout=btrl
> Bottom to top, right to left
> -o number-up-layout=lrbt
> Left to right, bottom to top
> -o number-up-layout=lrtb
> Left to right, top to bottom (default)
> -o number-up-layout=rlbt
> Right to left, bottom to top
> -o number-up-layout=rltb
> Right to left, top to bottom
> -o number-up-layout=tblr
> Top to bottom, left to right
> -o number-up-layout=tbrl
> Top to bottom, right to left
> ```

---

So I assume it will be something like this:

```
lp -o number-up=4 number-up-layout=lrtb -d {printer} {filename} -n {copies}
```

And it should print 4 images from left to right, top to bottom per page for the amount of {copies}. The numbers you can use seems fixed...

---

If this does not work please leave a comment.

Comment: Is there a way to set `-d` to print to a file, and not a printer?

Comment: This was not successful for me.  Using `-n 4 -o number-up=4` caused four sheets to be printed, each with a 1/4 scale copy of my work.

I got it to work by piping the output of pdftk like so:
`pdftk A=file.pdf cat A A A A output - | lp -o number-up=4 -`

Comment: @GuySoft nope. But I assume you can pipe it to a file ( > file.pdf) (?)

Comment: @Aoeuid nice one :)

Comment: @GuySoft a bit late for a reply, but perhaps this might be useful to someone else... On debian/ubuntu and similar you can install the `printer-driver-cups-pdf` package which will create a `PDF` printer (there are probably similar packages for other distributions). You can then use `pdftk A=file.pdf cat A A A A output - | lp -o number-up=4 -o number-up-layout=lrtb -d PDF -` and you will find your new pdf file in `~/PDF`.

Answer (score 3):

install gThumb (`sudo apt-get install gthumb`)

execute gThumb

select several image

right-click and select print

[image]

select image tab

increase Rows and Coulms

Comment: for screenshots better use  `LC_ALL=C command` to start the program!

Comment: What the heck would you use the C locale for? Since this site is mostly English, why not en-US.UTF-8?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` is quaranteed to work, locale `en_US.utf8` may be missing on the system so asking somebody to run `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 command` may end up not working. I agree that if real locale is available, it probably is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible and convenient with PhotoPrint.

Install the app in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install photoprint
```

When you open the image in the app, click it and choose from the menu *Image > Duplicate Image*. (also available via rightclick on the image)

Next you choose the amount of columns and/or rows you want to produce under *Layout*  and adjust the other settings like margins and  distances between the images.

You can save your settings as default under *File* in the menu.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: PhotoPrint is not supported on 20.04 at this moment. The anwer on the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179374/how-to-print-multiple-copies-of-an-image-on-a-single-page-gui?rq=1 also works.

Answer (score 1):

I was not satisfied with the answers so I came up with my own solution to print an image sixteen times on one sheet of paper:

```
# Append vertically.
convert Image.png Image.png Image.png Image.png -append Image_4_1.png
# Append horizontally.
convert Image_4_1.png Image_4_1.png Image_4_1.png Image_4_1.png +append Image_4_4.png
```

Now you can go ahead and print `Image_4_4.png`. You may want to delete `Image_4_1.png` afterwards. Works nicely with flashcards.