# How to print multiple copies of an image on a single page - gui

Tags: printing, image-processing, shotwell, image-viewers

I am looking for a GUI way to select one image file and print it multiple times on a single sheet of paper. This is basic functionality in other OS's, but my best shot for doing this in Ubuntu so far is this question: [How to print multiple copies of an image on a single page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433236/how-to-print-multiple-copies-of-an-image-on-a-single-page)

While that question got answers, they all seem to require either to use command-line, the will to workaround, or both. For many Ubuntu users that might be OK or a slight inconvenience (I find it quite annoying), but it's a no-go for many new users and discouraging for people considering to try out FLOSS.

Since other N-Up functionality, like printing a multi-page document with two or more pages per sheet of paper, works easily from most programs it would seem it should be trivial to achieve it for a single file. However, bugs like [this one on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/42189) indicate difficulties...

So where does the problem actually live? Is this feature missing from CUPS, or is it a problem of the various programs? Neither gThumb, Shotwell, Okular, Ristretto nor any of the other programs I tried does this in a simple, straightforward manner.

How can this functionality be added to the system print dialog?

Comment: Have a look at gLabels downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center. Set up a template with the number of 'labels' required, import the image and then print to your (presumably) A4 page.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to do it in the system print dialog, but I can with LibreOffice.

After installing [LibreOffice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) (if it isn't already on your system), open LibreOffice Writer and add your desired image to the page at its upper left.

Choose **Print**, then the **Page Layout** tab, and set the number of pages per sheet.

Go back to **General** and under **Range and Copies** choose **Pages**. Use the same page number(s) *n* times, where *n* is the number of instances to print per sheet. For a one page document printed *4* times on a sheet, enter: 1,1,1,1. To print *9* images on three successive sheets, enter: 1-9,1-9,1-9.

You may need to change from portrait to landscape page, if the image is not a square, so check first with **Print Preview**.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from any application, without the need for LibreOffice, by making a detour via **Print to File** (virtual printer) before printing to your physical printer.

1. Choose **Print** from any application, and choose **Print to File** as your printer.
2. Enter the number of times you want to print on a page as # **Copies**. For example, when you ultimately want to print 2x2 on one A4 page, select 4 copies. Keep the media size as normal, for example A4.
3. Hit **Print**, which by default creates an `output.pdf` in your home.
4. Open this PDF in the common **Evince Document Viewer**. In our example, it will have 4 copies of the same page as 4 separate pages.
5. Choose **Print**, and now choose your physical printer.
6. In the **Page Setup** tab, set **Pages per side** to the same amount of copies as before, which is 4 in our example. The paper size can stay as normal, for example A4.
7. Finally hit **Print**.