# How to automatically print multiple images per page?

Tags: automation, image-processing

Using an Ubuntu linux, what is the best/easiest way to print multiple images per page?

The global number of images and pages and the requested number of images per page should be dynamically chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application `digiKam` provides a feature called `Print Creator` with which different layouts of images per page can be applied to the previously selected images.

The created output can be exported to PDF, into a new image and printed directly or via Gimp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question you are asking was also mentioned in this link, hope this helps:
[How to print multiple copies of an image on a single page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433236/how-to-print-multiple-copies-of-an-image-on-a-single-page)

Comment: Thank you for this link! I saw this question as well, when searching for a solution, but have to admit that I had not checked all answers .... the first answers aren't automatic solutions - but further below, there are good proposals as well!

Answer (score 1):

I tried Shotwell app for multiple image print on one page.

Get **Shotwell**

`sudo apt install Shotwell`

- Import Gallery/ Folder
- Select Photos you want to print
- Go to Files (Select Print or CTRL+P)
  [image: File Menu]
- In **Print** go to Image Setting, you will see Autosize option (Fill the entire page) click on it scroll down to 4 image or 2 Images per page.
  [image: Print Option]
- Click Preview and Print

[image: Privew of Print3]

Your multiple images will be print on one single page.